# Stretch 2 html elements to fit into the parents full width

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/itzDa

How can I give the range slider the maximum width without line-breaking the span without using javascript?

I use IE9+ and latest chrome/FF etc.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="range" />
  <span>10 secs.</span>
</div>

#wrapper{
  width:600px;
  background:pink;
}
```

I forgot to mention that I do mobile first so if it does not work on IE9 thats ok. The fallback is that the slider is not max. strechted. :)

Comment: should you use display: block; for span?

Comment: He wants it without line-breaking, display: block will move the span under the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to do this:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: pink;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: box;
}
#wrapper input {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -moz-box-flex: 2;
  -ms-box-flex: 2;
  box-flex: 2;
  display: block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/itzDa

Comment: Your solution does not work on IE9 but this is not on mobile (forgot to mention I do mobile first) so its ok for me , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="range"] {
  width: 90%;
}
```

If the wrapper always has a fixed width (600px) and the span text can be small and big, it's depending on what range you got in mind for the slider,ou probably could do something like this: The span will always float on the right side this way.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="range" />
  <span>1088888 secs.</span>
  <div class="clear">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
  width:600px;
  background:pink;
}

input[type=range] {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

span {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

on both elements.  This will place them inline.

Flexbox isn't supported in IE 9, and floats can get wonky when working with document flow.(even with the clear as suggested).

If your text in the span is static, you can then adjust the range element to fit maximum width at your leisure.

source on flexbox (and any other css element) for cross browsers: http://caniuse.com/

Comment: "This will place them inline." My both elements were already placed in line before, thats not the problem. The left element must get maximum width without wrapping the right element. Your hint does not help for this task I tried it.

Comment: Ah, I see. My apologies. I misunderstood the question.  Glad you found your answer.